# How do you import "spark" from pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to test a utility function which takes in a spark DataFrame and outputs a new spark DataFrame after some transformations. In trying to mock data for the test, I need to construct a pyspark dataframe for the input. Most examples I see of this use

```
spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

I'm not too familiar with the docs and cannot find "spark". How do you `from pyspark* import spark`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark` is an instance of `SaprkSession` created as -

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Word Count") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Please follow - the pyspark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a way how to get the `spark` session variable, right?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .master("local") \
          .getOrCreate()
```

You can modify the session builder with several options.